# When performing git filter-branch --tree-filter, how to add the original commit SHA to the commit message?

Tags: git

I'm running a `--tree-filter` in order to move a couple of directories, with history, to another repo. I'd like to append a line to the commit message, something like

```
(Imported from ProjectA rev 684fa3....)
```

including the SHA of the corresponding commit in the original project.

How can I do this?

Comment: Probably by adding a `--msg-filter` or a `--commit-filter` to rewrite the commit message for each new commit made...

Comment: @twalberg FWIW, I did read the documentation, but somehow missed the paragraph that lists the available variables... an RTFM fail.

Answer (score 5):

[The original sha's available in `$GIT_COMMIT`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_filters):

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'cat; echo rewritten from $GIT_COMMIT' master
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502330/6309) (`git filter-branch --msg-filter 'cat;...'`):

Make sure to use git 2.7+ (Q4 2015) or git 2.4.1-, in case of multi-line commit message.

See [commit a5a4b3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5a4b3ff4d73be736984fd499551b1b0c10d33a1) (09 Oct 2015) by [James McCoy (`jamessan`)](https://github.com/jamessan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 44a9b53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44a9b53c599447a706dd4ae8a00fd8b4bed093b9), 20 Oct 2015)</sup>

> ### `filter-branch`: remove multi-line headers in msg filter

[df06201 (`filter-branch`: avoid passing commit message through `sed`)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df0620108b9710a06d5a2d9c125d43b97590cce6)
introduced a regression when filtering commits with multi-line headers,
if the header contains a blank line.
An example of this is a gpg-signed commit:

```
  $ git cat-file commit signed-commit
  tree 3d4038e029712da9fc59a72afbfcc90418451630
  parent 110eac945dc1713b27bdf49e74e5805db66971f0
  author A U Thor <author@example.com> 1112912413 -0700
  committer C O Mitter <committer@example.com> 1112912413 -0700
  gpgsig -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
   Version: GnuPG v1

   iEYEABECAAYFAlYXADwACgkQE7b1Hs3eQw23CACgldB/InRyDgQwyiFyMMm3zFpj
   pUsAnA+f3aMUsd9mNroloSmlOgL6jIMO
   =0Hgm
   -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

  Adding gpg
```

> As a consequence, "`filter-branch --msg-filter cat`" (which should leave the commit message unchanged) spills the signature (after the internal blank
>   line) into the original commit message.